# Separate a vector (or array) of strings separated by a "00"

Tags: c++, string

(C++) I have a vector of strings of different "categories". Each category is separated by a "00" string  in the vector.

So like:

"Pizza"
"IceCream" 
"Bread"
"00"
"Windows"
"Mac"
"Linux"
"Unix"
"00"
"Raining"
"Snowing"
"00"
"Hiking"
"00"

I am trying to figure out how to separate these categories into a vector of strings with all categories in one string like:

"Pizza IceCream Bread"
"Windows Mac Linux Unix"
"Raining Snowing"
"Hiking"

EDIT: alldoubles is the vector name and its size is totalsize

Attempt : Trying to add to a queue whenever the string is not 00

```
int loc = 0; //counter
    queue<string> tmp;
    string cur;
    while (loc<totalsize)
    {
        while (cur != "00")
        {
            tmp.push(cur); //add to queue when not 00
            loc = loc + 1;
            cur = alldoubles[loc];
        }

        while (tmp.empty()!=false)  //unload the queue into a string res 
        {                           // after an 00 was found and cout it
            string res;
            res = res + tmp.front();
            tmp.pop();
            cout << "RES " << res << endl;
        }
    }
```

EDIT : now I get RES and the RES Pizza which is not all the food with this code

```
int loc = 0;
queue<string> tmp;
string cur;
while (loc<totalsize)
{
    while (cur != "00")
    {
        tmp.push(cur);
        cur = alldoubles[loc];
        loc = loc+1;
    }

    while (!tmp.empty())
    {
        string res;
        res = res + tmp.front();
        tmp.pop();
        cout << "RES " << res << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: show us what you have tried

Comment: Ok I added my attempt but it doesn't work. It gets stuck in an infinite loop and I tried a couple things that didn't work.

Comment: Where do you assign a value to `totalsize`?

Comment: That's the size of my vector so I don't loop over the bounds of the vector. It was declared before. This is the relevant part of my program, the other functions work

Comment: Still not enough info. You aren't showing a declaration nor initialization of `alldoubles`. But I suspect that you are advancing `cur` past the end of that array, so of course it won't equal "00", forever.

Comment: Alldoubles is the vector with the categories separated by 00. I just added that info to the post to clarify

Comment: Can you also show the current output? Is there any right now?

Comment: Actually there is no output as the cout never runs

Comment: Have you tried printing the value of `cur` in the while loop? It might give a clue as to what's going on.

Comment: You never use alldouble[0]

Comment: You're right I didn't realize it skips the first one. Also the curr is at 00 during the time it is stuck in infinite loop. Nope totalsize is 10445 which is correct

Comment: Do you also think the general strategy that I am using is good, or should I do something else completely?

Comment: Strategy is not that bad....only not implemented correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> vv = { "one", "00",  "two", "three",  "00",  "four" , "five", "six",  "00", "seven" };

    std::string const splitter("00");

    // !!!! add 00 to the end
    vv.push_back(splitter);

    auto bb = vv.begin();
    auto it = std::find(vv.begin(), vv.end(), splitter);

    // finds groups and prints them one by one
    while (it != vv.end())
    {
        std::string accumulator;
        for(auto it2 = bb; it2 != it; ++it2)
            accumulator += *it2;

        bb = ++it;

        it = std::find(bb, vv.end(), splitter);
        std::cout << accumulator << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
one
twothree
fourfivesix
seven
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `while (tmp.empty()!=false)` by `while(!tmp.empty())`. At least....then you'll get something on `cout`.

Also, you need to initiate `cur` with `alldouble[0]` before using it.

Finally, `res` should be declared outside the last while loop, then, after the loop is executed, it should contain what you expected. By the way, don't forget to add spaces when you concatenate the elements into a final string.

It  should also be possible to construct `res` on the fly while checking '00' inside the first loop. Second `while` would not be needed anymore then.

Comment: Oh I did get something on cout now. How did that work? I get "RES "

Comment: empty returns true if the container is empty....and it's never empty in your case...so while condition is always false...

Comment: Your original loop only runs when `tmp.empty() != false` which is when `tmp.empty()`  is `true`.

Comment: Oh of course I shouldnt have used a !. That was a stupid mistake. However, ,the program still does not work correctl

Comment: @fman edited the post with more info on how res could be handled

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to C++11 there's a more idiomatic way using `algorithm` and `iterator` from the standard library.

```
std::vector<std::string> stuff = {"Pizza", "IceCream", "Bread", "00", "Windows", "Linux", "Mac", "00", "Raining", "Snowing", "00"};
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> results;

//find occurance of "00"
auto t = std::find(stuff.begin(), stuff.end(), "00");
//save previous position for copy starting point
auto t_old = stuff.begin(); 
while (t != stuff.end()) {
    //temporary vector to hold the strings in this segment
    auto accum = std::vector<std::string>( (t - t_old) );
    //copy from last "00" to next "00" into accum
    std::copy(t_old, t, accum.begin());
    //bump copy point to new location of next element after last found "00"
    t_old = t+1;
    //find next "00"
    t = std::find(t+1, stuff.end(), "00");
    results.push_back(accum);
}
```

This solution isn't perfect and doesn't attempt to concatenate the strings together but it's a good alternative approach that avoids many potential pitfalls.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution:

```
int main()
{
    vector<string> vec { "Pizza", "IceCream", "Bread", "00",
                         "Windows", "Mac", "Linux", "Unix", "00",
                         "Raining", "Snowing", "Hiking", "00" };

    int count {};
    string cat1;
    string cat2;
    string cat3;
    for_each(begin(vec), end(vec), [&](string str) {
        if (str == "00") {
            ++count;
            return;
        }
        if (count == 0) {
            for (auto& c : str) 
                cat1.push_back(c);
            cat1.push_back(' ');
        }
        if (count == 1) {
            for (auto& c : str) cat2.push_back(c);
            cat2.push_back(' ');
        }
        if (count == 2) {
            for (auto& c : str) cat3.push_back(c);
            cat3.push_back(' ');
        }
    });

    cout << cat1 << '\n';
    cout << cat2 << '\n';
    cout << cat3 << '\n';
}
```